# Add json values in to the list of object

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

How I can get all the values in this JSON and add all the value in to the list of object in the dart?

```
 "data": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "serviceId": 1017,
            "name": "اکو",
            "code": "235",
            "price": 1562500,
            "isDefault": true,
            "transportCostIncluded": false,
            "qty": 0,
            "minQty": 1,
            "maxQty": 2,
            "description": "یک دستگاه اکو به همراه دو باند و یک عدد میکروفن (تامین برق بعهده پیمانکار می باشد).",
            "contractorSharePercent": 65,
            "unitMeasureId": 7,
            "unitMeasureName": "هر 60 دقیقه",
            "superContractorsId": null
        },
       
    ],
```

like this `var list = ["2",1017,....]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've a JSON file, which you may have parsed like this:

```dart
String json = await rootBundle.loadString('file_name.json');
var response = jsonDecode(json);
```

This is how you can do it:

```dart
List<dynamic> jsonData; //similar to var jsonData = [something, something, ...]

//traversing through each value in the key value arrangement of the json
for (var k in response.values) {
   jsonData.add(k);  //adding each value to the list
}
```

After the loop ends, `jsonData` will have all the values of your JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

It's important for you to know that even if you put the keys on a list, they won't necessarily be in order, because of the way maps work.

Assuming your json is a map and not a json string, you could put all of the values on a list like so:

```
var myList = (jsonObject['data'] as List).fold<List>(
  [], 
  (prev, curr) => [...prev, ...curr.values]
);
```

if you were talking about a json string:

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonObject = jsonDecode(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, lets assume this json is unparsed in a string.

(1) Assuming the code snippet you added is a string && is valid json you can do as follows :)

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var x = json.decode('''
      {
        "data": [
            {
                "hello": "2",
                "serviceId": 1017,
                "name": "اکو",
                "code": "235",
                "price": 1562500,
                "isDefault": true,
                "transportCostIncluded": false,
                "qty": 0,
                "minQty": 1,
                "maxQty": 2,
                "description": "یک دستگاه اکو به همراه دو باند و یک عدد میکروفن (تامین برق بعهده پیمانکار می باشد).",
                "contractorSharePercent": 65,
                "unitMeasureId": 7,
                "unitMeasureName": "هر 60 دقیقه",
                "superContractorsId": null
            }
        ]
      }
  ''');
  print(x);
  List<dynamic> listOfObjects = (x['data'] as Iterable<dynamic>).toList();

  /// this is just gonna be a list of all of your object.
  print(listOfObjects);

  List<dynamic> listOfValues = (x['data'] as Iterable<dynamic>).map((_object) {
    return (_object as Map<String, dynamic>).values.toList();
  }).toList();

  /// this is gonna be a 2d array here,
  print(listOfValues);
}
```

Hope This helped out:)

Also json here comes from import 'dart:convert';